# how get and use a docker container id from part of its name in a terminal pipe request?

Tags: linux, docker, grep

I am trying to combine the following commands:

```
docker ps | grep track
```

that will give me

```
6b86b28a27b0        dev/jobservice/worker-jobtracking:3.5.0-SNAPSHOT   "/tini -- /startup/s…"   25 seconds ago      Up 2 seconds (health: starting)
                                                                                     jobservice_jobTrackingWorker_1
```

So then, I grab the id and use it in the next request as:

```
docker logs 6b8 | grep -A 3 'info'
```

So far, the easiest way I could find was to send those commands separately, but i wonder if there would be a simple way to do it.

I think that the main issue here is that I am trying to find the name of the container based on part of its name.

So, to resume, I would like to find and store the id of a container based on its name then use it to explore its logs.

Thanks!

Comment: Is that a Docker Compose managed container?  There are `docker-compose` equivalents to most useful commands that take the Compose service name; you should just be able to run `docker-compose logs jobTrackingWorker`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps there are cleaner ways to do it, but this works.

To get the ID of a partially matching container name:

```
$ docker ps --format "{{.ID}} {{.Names}}" | grep "partial" | cut -d " " -f1
```

Then you can use it in another bash command:

```
$ docker logs $(docker ps --format "{{.ID}} {{.Names}}" | grep "partial" | cut -d " " -f1)
```

Or wrap it in a function:

```
$ function dlog() { docker logs $(docker ps --format "{{.ID}} {{.Names}}" | grep "$1" | cut -d " " -f1); }
```

Which can then be used as:

```
$ dlog partial
```

Comment: working perfectly. To be noted that --filter is case sensitive so, in my case, I need to use "Track" while in docker ps | grep, I could use track

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell the pure bash approach to achieve what you want:

- With sudo:

  ```
  sudo docker ps | grep -i track - | awk '{print $1}' | head -1 | xargs sudo docker logs
  ```
- Without sudo:

  ```
  docker ps | grep -i track - | awk '{print $1}' | head -1 | xargs docker logs
  ```

Now let's break it down...

#### Let's see what containers I have running in my laptop for the Elixir programming language:

command:

```
sudo docker ps | grep -i elixir -
```

output:

```
0a19c6e305a2        exadra37/phoenix-dev:1.5.3_elixir-1.10.3_erlang-23.0.2_git   "iex -S mix phx.serv…"   7 days ago          Up 7 days             127.0.0.1:2000-2001->2000-2001/tcp                                                                    Projects_todo-tasks_app
65ef527065a8        exadra37/st3-3211-elixir:latest                              "bash"                   7 days ago          Up 7 days                                                                                                                   SUBL3_1600981599
232d8cfe04d5        exadra37/phoenix-dev:1.5.3_elixir-1.10.3_erlang-23.0.2_git   "mix phx.server"         8 days ago          Up 8 days             127.0.0.1:4000-4001->4000-4001/tcp                                                                    Staging_todo-tasks_app
```

#### Now let's find their ids:

command:

```
sudo docker ps | grep -i elixir - | awk '{print $1}'
```

output:

```
0a19c6e305a2
65ef527065a8
232d8cfe04d5
```

#### Let's get the first container ID:

command:

```
sudo docker ps | grep -i elixir - | awk '{print $1}' | head -1
```

> **NOTE**: replace `head -1` with `head -2` to get the second line in the output...

output:

```
0a19c6e305a2
```

#### Let's see the logs for the first container in the list

command:

```
sudo docker ps | grep -i elixir - | awk '{print $1}' | head -1 | xargs sudo docker logs
```

> **NOTE:** replace `head -1` with `tail -1` to get the logs for the last container in the list.

output:

```
[info] | module=WebIt.Live.Calendar.Socket function=mount/1 line=14  | Mount Calendar for date: 2020-09-30 23:29:38.229174Z
[debug] | module=Tzdata.ReleaseUpdater function=poll_for_update/0 line=40  | Tzdata polling for update.
[debug] | module=Tzdata.ReleaseUpdater function=poll_for_update/0 line=44  | Tzdata polling shows the loaded tz database is up to date.
```

Comment: great one too. It gets rid of the case sensitivity. I would simply remove the sudo to have it working (I am on Windows)

Comment: If my answer was useful you could upvote it to. Thanks.

Comment: Hey, I surely did vote, I might not have the privilege to have them appearing yet, sorry

Comment: I would like that the user that downvoted my answer would care to explain where I am wrong. We can only learn from each others if we share information :)

Answer (score 0):

Combining the different replies, I used:

`function dlog() { docker ps | grep -i track - | awk '{print $1}' | head -1 | xargs docker logs | grep -i -A 4 "$2";}`

to get the best of both worlds. So I can have a function that will have me type 4 letters instead of 2 commands and with no case sensitivity

I can then use `dlog keyword` to get my logs.

I hardcoded **track** and **-A 4** as I usually use that query but I could have passed them as arguments to add on modularity (my goal here was really simplicity)

Thanks for your help!